# How can we implement logic without using if else block instead of the within single query?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT column_key,
        Column_name
FROM tableA

UNION 
SELECT column_key,
        Column_name
FROM tableB
WHERE Database_Name = 'PROD'
  AND Table_Name = 'Document_Setup'
  AND Column_Name IN
      (
        'App_Advice',
        'Expect_Response_Time',
        'Matching_Interchanges',
        'Transmit')
```

Now I want to add new column check condition in second table when Doc_Standard_Name ='830' available then to add column name "Multiple_Transaction_Set" else it will work as what currently its working
But I don't want to write logic with two big if statement blocks. Can we implement with case Statement or other way?

```
 SELECT
      *
    FROM Document_Standard
    WHERE Document_key = @Document_key
      AND Doc_Standard_Name IN ('830')


SELECT column_key,
        Column_name
FROM tableA

UNION 
SELECT column_key,
        Column_name
FROM tableB
WHERE Database_Name = 'PROD'
  AND Table_Name = 'Document_Setup'
  AND Column_Name IN
      (
        'App_Advice',
        'Expect_Response_Time',
        'Matching_Interchanges',
        'Transmit',
        'Multiple_Transaction_Set')
```

I have written in this way, but don't want to write in if else block instead I want to handle this in a single block:

```
IF EXISTS

  (
     SELECT
      *
    FROM Document_Standard
    WHERE Document_key = @Document_key
      AND Doc_Standard_Name IN ('830')
  )
 BEGIN
    SELECT column_key,
            Column_name
    FROM tableA
    
    UNION 
    SELECT column_key,
            Column_name
    FROM tableB
    WHERE Database_Name = 'PROD'
  AND Table_Name = 'Document_Setup'
  AND Column_Name IN
        (
         'App_Advice',
         'Expect_Response_Time',
         'Matching_Interchanges',
         'Transmit')
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SELECT column_key,
        Column_name
    FROM tableA
    
    UNION 
    SELECT column_key,
            Column_name
    FROM tableB
    WHERE Database_Name = 'PROD'
  AND Table_Name = 'Document_Setup'
  AND Column_Name IN
        (
         'App_Advice',
         'Expect_Response_Time',
         'Matching_Interchanges',
         'Transmit',
         'Multiple_Transaction_Set')
            
 END;
```

Comment: People always seem to want to jump to control structures where what it sounds like you really need is to just use boolean operators (`AND` and `OR`) to specify which conditions need to be true together.

Comment: Your question is little confusing. I think you can try with case when then. it will be better if you share the sample data with result set.

Comment: What do you mean by *"add column name "Multiple_Transaction_Set""* Do you mean you want to expose another column in the `SELECT`? A query must be well defined, you can't have a `SELECT` that might have 2 columns, might have 3.

Comment: @AmitVerma I have added my solution. Hope you will get idea from it.

Comment: @Larnu, I have added my working Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some, `OR` logic:

```sql
SELECT column_key,
       Column_name
FROM tableA
UNION --ALL --Should this is UNION? UNION is a significantly more expensive; it should only be used if you need DISTINCT rows
SELECT column_key,
       Column_name
FROM tableA
WHERE Column_Name IN ('App_Advice', 'Expect_Response_Time', 'Matching_Interchanges', 'Transmit')
   OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM Document_Standard
               WHERE Document_key = @Document_key
                 AND Doc_Standard_Name IN ('830'))
   AND Column_Name = 'Multiple_Transaction_Set');
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Union clause because all rows are distinct.

Comment: That's fine, @Rahul , just many people seem to blanket use `UNION` when they should be using `UNION ALL`; as a result if i leave it as `UNION` I almost always leave such a note in the code, unless there is clear evidence that `UNION` is the correct operator

Comment: I have added 2 more conditions in where clause . It will have impact on above logic.

Comment: I have answered the question as it was, @Rahul . If you have a new question, post a new question. Don't make changes to your question that invalidate existing answers. Though it seems you just need to add the `WHERE` to your final code.

Comment: I guess above logic will work like either 4 column or 1 column.. but what I am expecting here is IF SELECT 1
               FROM Document_Standard
               WHERE Document_key = @Document_key
                 AND Doc_Standard_Name IN ('830') is then select all 5 columns other wise origional 4 colums

Comment: That logic is covered in the `EXISTS`, @Rahul ... And those 4/5 values aren't columns, they are literal strings; don't mix the two, they are completely different.